# Working out the volume of a hole in a sphere?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm revising for an AS-Level Maths exam and I have come across something we have never done before:

[image: sphere problem]

My initial thought was to use the fact that volume of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2 h$, but this doesn't take into account the curvature at the top, so I'm really not sure.

Comment: One option is account for the small cap (or rather, both of them) by computing the volume of the solid sector through the hole using spherical coordinates and subtracting the area of the cone with vertex at the center and with base bounded by the circular edge of the hole. (The problem doesn't seem to point this out, but notice the interesting fact that the given formula [6] is independent of $r$.)

Comment: Take the solid angle and subtact the volume of cone you have to get the curved volume

Comment: Totally lost me there haha. Solid sector through the hole?  Isn't the hole a hole though, so like its not solid?

Comment: $r^2=R^2-h^2/2$ from Pythagoras' theorem plugged in your formula for $V$ gives the right result [6]

Comment: @TiernanWatson You are correct: the volume of the hole is $\pi r^2h$. Note that by Pythagoras we have $R^2=\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)^2+r^2$, so $4R^2-h^2=4r^2$. So the given formula is the same as your answer.

Comment: Ah got it.  Feel silly.  Why did I think there would be invisible curves on the top that are part of the volume?  Thanks.  Used the Pythagora's theorem way.

Answer (score 0):

To get the volume, cylindrical coordinate system can be used. The sphere is $$r^2+z^2=R^2$$ Here r is not the hole radius. Let's use $r_h$ for that.

Then the volume of sphere with a hole at becomes, $$2 \pi \int_{r_h}^R \int_{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}rdzdr=\frac43 \pi h^3$$

Then the volume of hole becomes $$\frac43 \pi R^3-\frac 43 \pi h^3$$

Comment: Yes. Your first formula $\frac{4}{3}\pi h^3$ is the famous result that the volume of sphere remaining depends only on the height of the hole, not on the radius of the sphere! But you have calculated the volume removed, whereas it is clear from the question (and the answer it gives) that the required quantity is the volume of the cylindrical hole (which is much less for large $r_h$).

Comment: I see. To calculate buoyancy force, we need to calculate the volume inside the water. At that time, we may need go back to the first formula.